# Attachable property not found in generic type

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have a generic class `GridViewItemDragDrop<T>` in which a DependencyProperty is RegisterAttached:

```
namespace MobileAccess.ProjectExplorer.Library.Model.DragDrop
{
    public class GridViewItemDragDrop<T> where T : class
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsEnabled",
                                                typeof(bool),
                                                typeof(GridViewItemDragDrop<T>),
                                                new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsEnabledPropertyChanged)));
```

Now, when I want to instantiate this property from within a GridView like the following:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MobileAccess.ProjectExplorer.Library.Controls.WorkItemGridView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MobileAccess.ProjectExplorer.Library.Controls"
             xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:area="clr-namespace:MobileAccess.ProjectExplorer.Model.Area;assembly=MobileAccess.ProjectExplorer.Model"             
             xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             xmlns:aggregates="clr-namespace:MobileAccess.ProjectExplorer.Library.Aggregates"
             xmlns:dragdrop="clr-namespace:MobileAccess.ProjectExplorer.Library.Model.DragDrop">

<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="grvWorkItemItems" AllowDrop="True" dragdrop:GridViewItemDragDrop.IsEnabled="True"
                     d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=area:WorkItemViewItem}">
```

I get this in the error list:

> The attachable property 'IsEnabled' was not found in type 'GridViewItemDragDrop'.

and get this in the build output

> The property 'GridViewItemDragDrop.IsEnabled' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:MobileAccess.ProjectExplorer.Library.Model.DragDrop'

I have a feeling that this has something to do with the class being a generic class. I can't seem to find a way to make it work. A little help is much appreciated.

Comment: Where is the sense in making the owner type generic?

Comment: declare IsEnabledProperty in non-generic class? xaml doesn't support generics, and since static fields are one per closed generic type, GridViewItemDragDrop<T> will lead to existance of multiple IsEnabledProperty

Comment: Ok, I'll find a way to do this in a non-generic class. Thank you for your comment

Comment: "*find a way*"? Just drop the generic type parameter. Currently, it serves no purpose whatsoever. The property type is bool, the type of element on which the property is set can be anything derived from DependencyObject.